# Tax on Reseller commission and separate invoice

Tags: invoice, tax, customer-group

A client asks if it is possible to give resellers a commission and to charge Tax on that commission. They want to show the commission and the tax charged on the commission on the invoice. This needs to be a separate invoice only for resellers.

**The invoice will show:**

1. Travel price: € 1000
2. Commission (8,00%): € 40
3. Tax on commission (19%): € 7.60

I got a couple of questions which I hope someone can answer:

- What is the best way to give resellers commission in Magento?
- Is it possible to charge tax on that commission?
- Is it possible to send resellers a seperate invoice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several modules that let you implement extra fees like commission.

I reckon you should check those out, and see if one can suit your needs:

- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extra-fee-1.html
- http://www.mageworx.com/multi-fees-magento-extension.html
- http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-surcharge.html
- https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/extra-fee.html

By googling "Magento extra fee" you can find several more.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! We where able to fix this with the Fooman Surcharge plugin in combination with a regular discount. :)